# How to declare window using Drools Api

Tags: drools

I want to build the rule programmatically using Drools API.
I'm declaring sliding window using `PackageDescrBuilder`:

```
builder.newDeclare().window().name("timeWindow")
```

but I have no idea how to provide window type and parameter value (how to specify `window:length(3)`) ?

After further investigation I learned how to declare windows in DLR:

```
declare window DeclaredWindow
   StockTick( company == "DROO" ) over window:time( 5s )
end
```

I don't know how to do it using Drools API.

Comment: Did `.pattern(...)` not work? the WindowDeclarationDescrBuilder extends PatternContainerDescrBuilder, so that should be how you add a pattern ...

Comment: No, that did not work. My suspicion is that window support in Drool API is broken / unfinished.

Comment: Well possibly by doing it through the builders. It works perfectly fine in a drl.

Comment: I was asking specifically about the builders (Drools API).

Comment: Yes, but a blanket statement saying it does not work is incorrect since it only applies to the builders.

Comment: There was never blanket statement from my side. I was always reffering to Drools API. Drools API provides methods for declaring and refering to windows, but these methods simply DO NOT work. I could not found any example of using these methods in neither Drools Documentation nor Drools source code.